# How Intersect and Except result in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Have Two result Set A and B, In SSIS Merge Join how get EXCEPT and INTERSECT  of A result set.

[image]

Bellow sql syntax return desired out put:

```
---Insersect
select a.* from A a Inner join B b on a.Key=b.Key 

--Except
select a.* from A a left join B b on a.Key=b.Key where b.Key is null
```

How to get those query result from SSIS merge join

Comment: Did you notice that the merge join lets you select inner or left outer join?

Comment: @shamim is the problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to his [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/merge-join-transformation), *"The Merge Join transformation provides an output that is generated by joining two sorted datasets using a FULL, LEFT, or INNER join"*

In the Merge Join Transformation editor, you can select the `Join Type` property to do that:

**Except:**

> select a.* from A a left join B b on a.Key=b.Key where b.Key is null

You have to set `Join Type` = `Left Outer Join`, and after the `Merge Join Transformation` you have to add a conditional split to filter rows that has `b.Key is null`

Follow this detailed article for that: [Get all from Table A that isn't in Table B](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Get-all-from-Table-A-that-isnt-in-Table-B.aspx)

**Intersect**

> select a.* from A a Inner join B b on a.Key=b.Key

You have to set `Join Type` = `Inner Join`

Follow this article for that: [Inner join in SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7fde75e6-4a7d-4b95-ac46-ec93b8c8592b/inner-join-in-ssis-?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: @Haid, thank for your valuable information , yah it's really helpful for me.Thank you.

Comment: @shamim accepting an answer means that it solved your issue, but it doesn't mean that it is helpful. You have to upvote answers that you find them helpful. Not only say that in comments. for the same reason i already upvoted this question to say that it is helpful